# How to compress csv encoded file into zip archive directly?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, encoding, zip

I want to write data to cp1250 encoded file and zip it without temporary storing it on filesystem.

I figured out that I need someting like this

```
f = io.TextIOBase(newline='', encoding='cp1250')
writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';', dialect='excel', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
writer.writerow([3,3,3,4])
with ZipFile('cvs.zip', 'w') as zip_file:
    zip_file.writestr('test.cvs', f.getvalue())
```

But now on third line I got:

```
io.UnsupportedOperation: write
```

This is probably because of use io.TextIOBase, but with any stringIO i can't set encoding